# Error Correction for findViewById() - What's the return value?

Tags: java, android

I'm receiving several space names which I save in my variable "space", I  then need to change visibility for that space image, but if that image space does not exist then it just continues.
What I want to do is something like this:

```
ImageView greenball = (ImageView)findViewById(resgreenball);
if(greenball != NULL)    /* <---- ERROR HERE*/
     greenball.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The compiler gives me an error when trying to compare greenball with NULL.

How can I manage this?
Because not all "space"s I receive are an imageview, just some of them.

Thanks!

Comment: The null keyword for Java is `null`, all lowercase

Comment: Thanks! the null in lowercase solved the problem! been programming C for a long time, I was going NUTS!